# java.io.IOException - Java

Tags: java, threadpool, websphere-8

I am getting repeatedly below error while running java application on IBM - WebSphere Application Server.

```
[ 00000024 TCP E org.jgroups.protocols.TP$IncomingPacket run failed handling incoming message
                    java.io.IOException: failed reading header
at org.jgroups.Message.readHeader(Message.java:757)
at org.jgroups.Message.readFrom(Message.java:643)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.readMessage(TP.java:1502)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.access$700(TP.java:49)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$IncomingPacket.run(TP.java:1804)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:773)
        Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:309)
at org.jgroups.Message.readHeader(Message.java:734)
... 7 more


java.io.IOException: failed reading header
at org.jgroups.Message.readHeader(Message.java:757)
at org.jgroups.Message.readFrom(Message.java:643)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.readMessage(TP.java:1502)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.access$700(TP.java:49)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$IncomingPacket.run(TP.java:1804)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1763)
at org.jgroups.util.ShutdownRejectedExecutionHandler.rejectedExecution(ShutdownRejectedExecutionHandler.java:39)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:779)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:667)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.dispatchToThreadPool(TP.java:1354)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.receive(TP.java:1321)
at org.jgroups.protocols.BasicTCP.receive(BasicTCP.java:258)
at org.jgroups.blocks.BasicConnectionTable.receive(BasicConnectionTable.java:239)
at    org.jgroups.blocks.BasicConnectionTable$Connection.run(BasicConnectionTable.java:664)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:773)

Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:309)
at org.jgroups.Message.readHeader(Message.java:734)
... 14 more
```

Application has file export operation. Somehow files are deleted from specified location and whenever I try to run application through above exception continuously. I tried killing java but that too do not help.

Please suggest how to resolve.

Comment: Have some data there to read.

Comment: Please tell us something about your application.  There is no way to figure out what's going wrong from only a stack trace while knowing nothing about the code.

Comment: It's pretty easy to tell what's going wrong -- EOF in org.jgroups.Message.readHeader at line 734.  Strongly suggestive of a file that is empty or isn't there at all.  (If the data being processed there is not a file but, eg, network data, the data is too short.)

Comment: @HotLicks I meant the ultimate cause of the error, rather than the proximate cause. i.e. We can't know *why* there is no data to read.

Comment: But one would start debugging this by looking at line 734, figuring out what file was being read and where it came from.  Something the OP should have done already.

Comment: I can believe on Hot Licks suggestion actually in my application there is a file export operation. I have removed old file from there and it may application whenever runs looking for it but unable to found and through IOException. Is there any option to stop this search. Killing java do not help. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Stop IBM Webservice application already started services from services.msc :)